# Can't create a EditModel for byte

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

My class have an Image Property as byte[]. 
I want create a EditTemplate for byte so a drag and drop area appear there instead.

When i try to create the View with name "byte" say

> Add View: The name invalid because it is a reserved name

I understand the view have to be same name as the DataType you are trying to create the template.

For example I can create an EditorTemplate for "DateTime"

So how should I Create my EditTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` is a class name, `byte` is a C# reserved keyword that is an alias for `System.Byte`.  See the list of keywords here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Change the type to Byte (instead of byte) and it should work.. if not, then you can always do this in your model:

```
[UIHint("ByteTemplate")]
byte[] Image {get;set;}
```

Then create a ByteTemplate.cshtml template.

You can also use the template selection overload of `EditorFor(x => x.Image, "ByteTemplate");`